# jQuery Mobile behaving weirdly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am loading my home page which has tabs. Am loading the content of the first tab using ajax in pageinit function. There is a link on home page which leads to another page(which is a separate html file). The link is a plain  to the other page. For some reason, when we tap on the browser back link and come back the home page gets superimposed on the other page. ANd, the nav tabs are getting bigger. Dont know what is the issue here.Any help on this. hope that am clear. Am executing the pageinit function like below.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', "#home", function() {
 $.ajax({
  url : "sportstabcontent.html",
  dataType : "html",
  success : function(data) {
   $("#newssection").html(data);
   $("#newsitems").listview().listview('refresh');
   $('.viewMoreNewsBtn').attr('data-role', 'button').button().trigger('create');
  }
 });
});
```

Should I do the loading of the above ajax code into pageshow. I tried even that. Still it is behaving wierdly.

Comment: dont know why am given negative votes for a genuine question for the issue which am facing

Comment: ok, add the same code with a `navigate` listener. `$( window ).on( "navigate", function () { the same above without pageinite of course });`. OR force reloading that page also using navigate `$( window ).on( "navigate", function () { $.mobile.changePage('URL',{ reloadPage: true }); });`

Comment: I found the issue happens when we switch tabs on the home page and then click the link on the home page and go to the other page. This is the code i use for tab switch:$.ajax({
   url : pageName,
   dataType : "html",
   success : function(data) {
    
    $(divId).html(data);
    if(isNewsSection){
     $("#newsitems").listview().listview('refresh');
     $('.viewMoreNewsBtn').attr('data-role', 'button').button().trigger('create');
    }}

Comment: have you tried the code in my previous comment?

Comment: omar why should i do all this for no reason. changePage is automatically handled by jquery mobile. isn't it. why should i force the page to reload.

Comment: To check if this solved the problem or at least give us more insight on your problem.

Comment: When i tap the link on home page and go to the other page, both the pages are in the dom. That is why it looks like it is superimposed. This happens only if i switch tabs on home page, which makes an ajax call and inserts data into the dom, and then click on the home page link. Otherwise, tapping on the home page link works fine.

Comment: Then you should either remove previously injected data or check if it exists before you make your ajax call.

Comment: Observed one behaviour. When i tap on the link on home page, it loads both the home page url and the other page url. This is happening only when loading using ajax. If i make data-ajax="false" then there is no issue.

Comment: If possible can you mail me your project or if it is not your property can you create a smaller version of your site (just bare bone to recreate this problem) and mail it to me: dragan.gaic@gmail.com I will check it and hopefully fix it. It is really hard to debug something when you only see a fraction of a picture.

Comment: Gajotres- i have created and mailed you a sample demo. Please check and reply to my mail. Thanks.