# JQuery Mobile - Does it make mobile development easy?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am getting the following issues while using jquery mobile. Is Jquery mobile worth using in big projects?

1. When we do scrolling, there is flickering issue. This is not during transition.
2. And, using ajax causes weird behaviour. Sometimes, it loads the same page, before loading a link's page. I have disabled ajax mode as false in 'mobileinit'. AJAX way of doing things in jquery mobile is not straight forward. It causes unnecessary wierd issues. Morevoer, we cannot put anything in another page's head section.
3. Very difficult to trace the styles and change it, when you want to override the styles.

Can you all guys who are using jquery mobile share their views and solutions if you have found any for the above problems. And, your experience in using jqm. We have knowingly or unknowingly started using jqm for our project. Don't know jqm makes life easy or complex :-)

Comment: SO is a place for posting your code and getting help with it. Unknowingly started using jqm? How could you not know?

Comment: This is one link posted by me in stackoveflow for which there is no concrete answer from anyone: :-(                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566092/jquery-mobile-behaving-weirdly

Comment: There is a guy on that thread trying to help you but you have been resistant to his suggestions. Just because you post a question doesn't mean that there is going to be a solid answer. Maybe you need to rephrase or provide demo?

Comment: My idea here in posting this question is to find out the problems faced by others. Am not against jqm.

Comment: Never said that you were against it, just pointed out that this is not the kind of question that SO expects. I am sure that it will likely go unanswered and may even be closed by SO.

Comment: jQuery Mobile makes life easier yet it's not perfect 100%. You'll probably encounter obstacles, and you should make your way through. You can integrate JQM with other plugins to achieve the results you want. Life isn't easy my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what do you count as a big project. People usually forget one thing, **`jQuery Mobile`** was build to work on all major browser environments and will it holds suffix it is more then that. At the same time it doesn't mean it is `"mobile only"`. While it behaves more then excellent on a desktop browsers it has certain problems running on a mobile devices. There's only one major reasons for pure mobile usability and it is a no real optimization for a mobile devices. What ever people think an optimized and fully responsive HTML5 hybrid application is just a nice dream. Sad truth is mobile devices performances are still faaar faaar behind they older desktop brother.

If you really want to create a hybrid mobile app better look towards **[AppFramework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/)** (ex **`jqMoby`**) or **[Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)** because they will provide you with much better optimization not to mention 2-3 x faster execution. still even their will perform purely in some instances.

But let me answer your questions.

1. This is a real **`jQuery Mobile`** problem, no matter which mobile device is used sooner or later it will suffer from flickering problem. An perfect solution don't exist. Unless you count switching to **`AppFramework`**, but while you will gain much better usability it is just another horror story.
2. in 99,9% of cases this is not a jQuery Mobile problem, mostly they are due to lack of understanding how **`jQuery Mobile`** works. Please in case of this problems share them with us, we will provide you with a solution.
3. And this is far from truth. I have worked on many mobile frameworks and **`jQuery Mobile`** has a very clean css styling and page structure. To be honest it was very scary for me to work with it first few weeks but after some time you can override it styling without using tools like Firebug.

Basically everything here comes to one question. What are your needs? If you want to create a responsive hybrid mobile app then steer clear form **`jQuery Mobile`** and look at a solution I provided you at the begging of this answer. While good on newer mobile phones it will simply run purely on an older ones (version 1.4 should bring speed improvements but I don't think they will match **`AppFramework`**). On the other hand if you are building a mobile version of your site or just enhancing your regular site the **`jQuery Mobile`** is a tool for you.

Comment: +1 well said, although its not perfect, yet it saves you hell of time styling and coding.

Comment: Gajotres, you are always straight to the answer. Thanks a lot. Have few questions: 1. We are developing a mobile site. We are using jquery mobile. We have different design for smart phone, feature phones. Can I use jquery mobile for feature phones also.

Comment: 2. Can you please help me on the second question. Here is the link to the problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566092/jquery-mobile-behaving-weirdly. If I disable ajax for the link, it is working fine. 3. Since am getting problems while using ajax, i have disabled it globally to navigate between pages. Is it fine to do this, or will it cause any issues. 3. On flickering issue, it happens during scrolling on android device. It is so evident which creates a very bad user experience.

Comment: Let me answer you your first question. Don't use jQM on feature phones. Basically look how it runs on smartphones now think what would happen on even slower platform. I would advise you to create a very dumb down site for feature phones. You can use some of mobile phone detection tools to make a difference between smart and feature phones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055277/what-are-available-solutions-of-a-browser-mobile-phone-detection/15055352#15055352

Comment: Thanks Gakotres. Can you please help on the second question.

Comment: Take a look at a comment I left in your second question comments section.

Comment: Gajotres- Want to know whether we can do something for the flickering issue on jquery mobile. Was testing the site on android device. Seems to be having more evident flickering. Is there anyway we can reduce the flickering. On iPhone, there seems to be no flickering.